# Why does ios_base offer an iword array and a pword array?

Tags: c++, iostream

The `ios_base`, which is the very top class of the iostream hierarchy, offers some public APIs to allocate an dynamic array of ints and pointers, notably the `pword()` and `iword()` and `xalloc()` family. After 4 years of programming in this language, I have never been given a chance to use them. They seem to very low level operation, isn't it? If they aren't used in an every day basic, why they stay in the library? It is not wise to waste memory or offer useless API.

Comment: I've already use them once. It's used to store information that persist (at least) until the next operation on the stream. You can store inside formatting information that will be used on your next output. Like std::cout << MyFormattingInfo(23) << myvariable; The "MyFormattingInfo(23)" will store something usefull inside those iword/pword and the operator<<() myvariable will use it.

Comment: I am not sure why you are bundling locale and streambuf. While allocating memory within the stream is not used very often (mostly by custom-built manipulators) locales and buffers are very useful things.

Comment: These are _private storage_ one can use. The design of IOStreams is rather dated and not considered good practice to copy.